# Stop the phone from disconnecting Discord calls

Tags: discord

My phone is an LG K40+. Sometimes when I'm on a call on Discord, it'll disconnect from the call. I'm connected via WiFi and the quality is fine, so I don't think it's an internet issue.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling battery optimisation for Discord only, eventually that will work.